# Spark Application Log Solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark, emr

I have a Spark (1.3.1) application with Python, running on YARN, EMR clusters and using the S3 like storage. 
My application transform a CSV file in a RDD and performs regex transformations (ETL).
We need create a level line log solution for error capture and identification of source problem (record and column).
I don't have any idea about this.

```python
def lineMap(column):
   return (
        column[1],
        column[2]
   )

fileContent = sc.textFile(s3FilePathInput)

RDDcru = (fileContent
                .map(lambda x : x.split(";"))
                .map(lineMap)
            )
```

I've trying create a try - catch block on lineMap function, using logging default python lib. 
I tried also, create a new SparkContext writting a file log on S3 (on catch block)

All failed ...

Thank's and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

A resolution for this case is create a new field of log.

```python
def etl_func(col,log):
   try:
      (code)
    except Exception,e:
      log.append(str(e))

 def lineMap(column):
   log = []
   return (
        etl_func(column[1],log),
                 column[2],
                 log
   )
```